# Android's EditText not receiving keyboard input correctly

Tags: android, android-edittext

Just found myself trying to figure out this strange behavior in for EditText.

Information:
Bug seems to only happen in some devices! for now I've only seen it in Sony Xperia D2303.

App description:
I'm working on an app that has a main activity and navigation is done trough different fragments that are replaced as user moves from one section to another.
At one point I'm showing a DialogFragment with an edit text field, with background set to @null, with a hint text. (I have also tried with a normal edit text, taken from widget list and dragged to the layout and found the same behavior).

Problem:
When clicking on the EditText, software keyboard SHOWS UP but when typing there is no letter input in the EditText!  I can long press, to visualize cursor position marker and also the magnifying glass shows up.

Things I've tried:
- I've tried requesting focus with xml, programmatically.
- Setting touchable(in touch mode also)
- Setting *descendantFocusability* attribute of parent to '*afterDescendants*'
- Overriding onTouchListener and showing keyboard programmatically through the InputManager and using the edit text's token
… and maybe other things which I don't remember

There is but a **workaround** that I've found!!!   sending the app to background, and bringing it to foreground again…  so it seems something related to focus maybe?? but then why does keyboard show up, and cursor marker and magnifying glass work?

This solution does not work for me as it depends on the user taking action

Has anyone found this problem? any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you long press is the cursor in the beginning position of the ``editText`` or has it moved a number of characters typed?

Comment: The cursor stays at the beginning…  instead with the magnifying glass I can move to the length of the hint text

Comment: I have seen similar problem. Looking for workaround as well.